# How do Functions work in a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema where I'm trying to generate a [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) to show on the front end. (The default MongoDB ObjectID is too long to display to users.)

What I've done is to insert it into my schema as a default value that generates a new string each time an instance of the model is created.

These are the instructions provided by the nanoid docs for dealing with Mongoose

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid()
  }
})
```

I've replicated this in my code:

```
const MySchema = new Schema(
  {
  // a bunch of other properties 
  nano_id: {
      type: String,
      default: () => nanoid()
    }
  },
  { autoIndex: true },
)
```

The problem I've run into is that for whatever reason. When I use my UI to create a new model with this new code on the back end, after hitting the submit button, the state changes to loading and gets stuck there.

I found a little hack where I can save my code in VSCode which forces a hot reload. This breaks out of the loading stage where I can then resubmit and it works as expected - nanoid is generated, displayed every where I want it, etc.

When my new nano_id property is removed from the Schema, I don't have to do this reloading hack to get it to save. So I know the bug has something to do with this.

What is actually happening with the syntax `default: () => nanoid()`?

My hypothesis is that there is some promise that is being generated or something that isn't resolving properly. Can't seem to find anything about this in the docs though. Other than related specifically to `Date` and `Date.now`, which I'm already using and is working fine.

Edit: adding function code

```
// at top of file where Schema is defined 
const { customAlphabet } = require('nanoid');
const alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const nanoid = customAlphabet(alphabet, 8);
```

Edit: adding request handler

```
router.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.body
  // Map request payload to Referral Model
  const new_referral = new Referral({
    referral_status: payload.referral_status,
    referral_agency: payload.referral_agency,
    date_assigned: payload.date_assigned,
    referral_source: payload.referral_source,
    referral_source_email: payload.referral_source_email,
    referral_source_name: payload.referral_source_name,
    referral_title: payload.referral_title,
    referral_source_phone: payload.referral_source_phone,
    referral_need: payload.referral_need || [],
    additional_details: payload.additional_details,
    dob: payload.dob,
    last_name: payload.last_name,
    first_name: payload.first_name,
    middle_name: payload.middle_name,
    gender: payload.gender,
    language: payload.language,
    address_1: payload.address_1,
    address_2: payload.address_2,
    city: payload.city,
    state: payload.state,
    county: payload.county,
    zip: payload.zip,
    mailing_address_1: payload.mailing_address_1,
    mailing_address_2: payload.mailing_address_2,
    mailing_city: payload.mailing_city,
    mailing_state: payload.mailing_state,
    mailing_zip: payload.mailing_zip,
    phone: payload.phone,
    primary_phone_valid: payload.primary_phone_valid,
    phone_secondary: payload.phone_secondary,
    secondary_phone_valid: payload.secondary_phone_valid,
    leave_message: payload.leave_message,
    insurance_1: payload.insurance_1,
    insurance_1_plan: payload.insurance_1_plan,
    insurance_1_group_number: payload.insurance_1_group_number,
    insurance_1_policy_number: payload.insurance_1_policy_number,
    insurance_2: payload.insurance_2,
    insurance_2_plan: payload.insurance_2_plan,
    insurance_2_group_number: payload.insurance_2_group_number,
    insurance_2_policy_number: payload.insurance_2_policy_number,
    insurance_3: payload.insurance_3,
    insurance_3_plan: payload.insurance_3_plan,
    insurance_3_group_number: payload.insurance_3_group_number,
    insurance_3_policy_number: payload.insurance_3_policy_number,
    appointment_availability: payload.appointment_availability,
    preferred_times: payload.preferred_times,
    appointment_date: payload.appointment_date,
    appointment_time: payload.appointment_time,
    assessment_harp: payload.assessment_harp,
    assessment_contact_date: payload.assessment_contact_date,
    assessment_date_completed: payload.assessment_date_completed,
    assessment_date_submitted: payload.assessment_date_submitted,
    assessment_date_approved: payload.assessment_date_approved,
    cin: payload.cin,
    number_cancelled: payload.number_cancelled,
    number_noshows: payload.number_noshows,
    date_received: payload.date_received,
    history: payload.history,
    consent: payload.consent,
    consent_date: payload.date_received,
    project: payload.project || null,
    contact_needs: payload.contact_needs || [],
    contact_type: payload.contact_type || [],
    notes: payload.notes,
    contact_details: payload.contact_details,
    contact_date: payload.contact_date,
    contact_time: payload.contact_time,
    number_of_contacts: payload.number_of_contacts,
    address_type: payload.address_type,
    shelter_name: payload.shelter_name,
    address_valid: payload.address_valid,
    agency_therapist: payload.agency_therapist,
    phone_agency_therapist: payload.phone_agency_therapist,
    email_agency_therapist: payload.email_agency_therapist,
    agency_prescribing_clinician: payload.agency_prescribing_clinician,
    phone_agency_prescribing_clinician:
      payload.phone_agency_prescribing_clinician,
    email_agency_prescribing_clinician:
      payload.email_agency_prescribing_clinician,
    primary_care_provider: payload.primary_care_provider,
    phone_primary_care_provider: payload.phone_primary_care_provider,
    email_primary_care_provider: payload.email_primary_care_provider,
    email_client: payload.email_client,
    referral_encounter_note: payload.referral_encounter_note,
    health_home_enrolled: payload.health_home_enrolled,
    health_home_facility: payload.health_home_facility,
    health_home_enrollment_date: payload.health_home_enrollment_date,
    care_management_enrolled: payload.care_management_enrolled,
    care_management_facility: payload.care_management_facility,
    care_management_enrollment_date: payload.care_management_enrollment_date,
    last_annual_physical_date: payload.last_annual_physical_date,
    last_pcp_followup_date: payload.last_pcp_followup_date,
    last_annual_physical_time: payload.last_annual_physical_time,
    last_pcp_followup_time: payload.last_pcp_followup_time,
    insurance_1_effective_date: payload.insurance_1_effective_date,
    insurance_1_expiration_date: payload.insurance_1_expiration_date,
    insurance_2_effective_date: payload.insurance_2_effective_date,
    insurance_2_expiration_date: payload.insurance_2_expiration_date,
    insurance_3_effective_date: payload.insurance_3_effective_date,
    insurance_3_expiration_date: payload.insurance_3_expiration_date,
    qm_1_checkbox: payload.qm_1_checkbox,
    qm_1_date: payload.qm_1_date,
    qm_2_checkbox: payload.qm_2_checkbox,
    qm_2_date: payload.qm_2_date,
    qm_3_checkbox: payload.qm_3_checkbox,
    qm_3_date: payload.qm_3_date,
    qm_4_checkbox: payload.qm_4_checkbox,
    qm_4_date: payload.qm_4_date,
    qm_5_checkbox: payload.qm_5_checkbox,
    qm_5_date: payload.qm_5_date,
    qm_6_checkbox: payload.qm_6_checkbox,
    qm_6_date: payload.qm_6_date,
    is_guardian: payload.is_guardian,
    guardian_first_name: payload.guardian_first_name,
    guardian_last_name: payload.guardian_last_name,
    engagement_contact_type: payload.engagement_contact_type,
    engagement_date: payload.engagement_date,
    engagement_time: payload.engagement_time,
    engagement_number_of_contacts: payload.engagement_number_of_contacts,
    engagement_contact_details: payload.engagement_contact_details,
    active_duty: payload.active_duty,
    veteran: payload.veteran,
    programs: payload.programs,
    outcomes: payload.outcomes,
    user_access: payload.user_access,
    ethnicity: payload.ethnicity,
    quality_metrics: payload.quality_metrics,
    hospital_site_address: payload.hospital_site_address,
    hospital_site_name: payload.hospital_site_name,
    hospital_site_npi: payload.hospital_site_npi,
    hospital_site_phone: payload.hospital_site_phone,
    pcp_site_name: payload.pcp_site_name,
    pcp_name: payload.pcp_name,
    pcp_npi: payload.pcp_npi,
    pcp_phone: payload.pcp_phone,
    pcp_address: payload.pcp_address,
    care_management: {
      contact_needs: payload.care_management_contact_needs,
      contact_type: payload.care_management_contact_type,
      number_of_contacts: payload.care_management_number_of_contacts,
      appointment_date: payload.care_management_appointment_date,
      appointment_time: payload.care_management_appointment_time,
      contact_date: payload.care_management_contact_date,
      contact_time: payload.care_management_contact_time,
      contact_details: payload.care_management_contact_details,
      contact_duration: payload.care_management_contact_duration,
      number_of_contacts: payload.care_management_number_of_contacts,
    },
    peer_services: {
      outcome_of_intervention: payload.peer_services_outcome_of_intervention,
      contact_needs: payload.peer_services_contact_needs,
      contact_type: payload.peer_services_contact_type,
      number_of_contacts: payload.peer_services_number_of_contacts,
      appointment_date: payload.peer_services_appointment_date,
      appointment_time: payload.peer_services_appointment_time,
      contact_date: payload.peer_services_contact_date,
      contact_time: payload.peer_services_contact_time,
      contact_details: payload.peer_services_contact_details,
      contact_duration: payload.peer_services_contact_duration,
      number_of_contacts: payload.peer_services_number_of_contacts,
    },
    physical_health: {
      contact_needs: payload.physical_health_contact_needs,
      contact_type: payload.physical_health_contact_type,
      number_of_contacts: payload.physical_health_number_of_contacts,
      contact_date: payload.physical_health_contact_date,
      contact_time: payload.physical_health_contact_time,
      contact_details: payload.physical_health_contact_details,
      contact_duration: payload.physical_health_contact_duration,
      number_of_contacts: payload.physical_health_number_of_contacts,
      hospital_site_address: payload.physical_health_hospital_site_address,
      hospital_site_name: payload.physical_health_hospital_site_name,
      hospital_site_npi: payload.physical_health_hospital_site_npi,
      hospital_site_phone: payload.physical_health_hospital_site_phone,
      pcp_site_name: payload.physical_health_pcp_site_name,
      pcp_name: payload.physical_health_pcp_name,
      pcp_npi: payload.physical_health_pcp_npi,
      pcp_phone: payload.physical_health_pcp_phone,
      pcp_address: payload.physical_health_pcp_address,
      pcp_appointment_date: payload.physical_health_pcp_appointment_date,
      pcp_appointment_time: payload.physical_health_pcp_appointment_time,
      last_pcp_followup_date: payload.physical_health_last_pcp_followup_date,
      last_pcp_followup_time: payload.physical_health_last_pcp_followup_time,
      last_annual_physical_date:
        payload.physical_health_last_annual_physical_date,
      last_annual_physical_time:
        payload.physical_health_last_annual_physical_time,
      breast_cancer_screening: payload.breast_cancer_screening,
      breast_cancer_screening_date: payload.breast_cancer_screening_date,
      well_child_visit_3_18: payload.well_child_visit_3_18,
      well_child_visit_3_18_date: payload.well_child_visit_3_18_date,
      well_child_first_30: payload.well_child_first_30,
      well_child_first_30_date: payload.well_child_first_30_date,
      seven_day_hospital_follow_up: payload.seven_day_hospital_follow_up,
      seven_day_hospital_follow_up_date:
        payload.seven_day_hospital_follow_up_date,
      thirty_day_hospital_follow_up: payload.thirty_day_hospital_follow_up,
      thirty_day_hospital_follow_up_date:
        payload.thirty_day_hospital_follow_up_date,
      emergency_dept_follow_up: payload.emergency_dept_follow_up,
      emergency_dept_follow_up_date: payload.emergency_dept_follow_up_date,
      diabetes_screening_schizo_bipolar:
        payload.diabetes_screening_schizo_bipolar,
      diabetes_screening_schizo_bipolar_date:
        payload.diabetes_screening_schizo_bipolar_date,
      potential_avoidable_ed_utilization:
        payload.potential_avoidable_ed_utilization,
      potential_avoidable_ed_utilization_date:
        payload.potential_avoidable_ed_utilization_date,
      cervical_cancer_screening: payload.cervical_cancer_screening,
      cervical_cancer_screening_date: payload.cervical_cancer_screening_date,
      csc_eye: payload.csc_eye,
      csc_eye_date: payload.csc_eye_date,
      amr: payload.amr,
      amr_date: payload.amr_date,
      col: payload.col,
      col_date: payload.col_date,
    },
    outpatient_mental_health: {
      contact_needs: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_needs,
      contact_type: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_type,
      number_of_contacts: payload.outpatient_mental_number_of_contacts,
      appointment_date: payload.outpatient_mental_appointment_date,
      appointment_time: payload.outpatient_mental_appointment_time,
      contact_date: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_date,
      contact_time: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_time,
      contact_details: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_details,
      contact_duration: payload.outpatient_mental_contact_duration,
      number_of_contacts: payload.outpatient_mental_number_of_contacts,
      type_of_appointment: payload.outpatient_mental_type_of_appointment,
      diagnosis: payload.outpatient_mental_diagnosis,
      grpa: payload.outpatient_mental_grpa,
      grpa_date_completed: payload.outpatient_mental_grpa_date_completed,
      grpa_frequency: payload.outpatient_mental_grpa_frequency,
      noms: payload.outpatient_mental_noms,
      noms_date_completed: payload.outpatient_mental_noms_date_completed,
      noms_frequency: payload.outpatient_mental_noms_frequency,
    },
    outpatient_substance_use: {
      contact_needs: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_needs,
      contact_type: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_type,
      number_of_contacts: payload.outpatient_substance_number_of_contacts,
      appointment_date: payload.outpatient_substance_appointment_date,
      appointment_time: payload.outpatient_substance_appointment_time,
      contact_date: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_date,
      contact_time: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_time,
      contact_details: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_details,
      contact_duration: payload.outpatient_substance_contact_duration,
      number_of_contacts: payload.outpatient_substance_number_of_contacts,
      type_of_appointment: payload.outpatient_substance_type_of_appointment,
      diagnosis: payload.outpatient_substance_diagnosis,
      grpa: payload.outpatient_substance_grpa,
      grpa_date_completed: payload.outpatient_substance_grpa_date_completed,
      grpa_frequency: payload.outpatient_mental_grpa_frequency,
      noms: payload.outpatient_substance_noms,
      noms_date_completed: payload.outpatient_substance_noms_date_completed,
      noms_frequency: payload.outpatient_mental_noms_frequency,
    },
  })

  if (!payload.duplicate_skip) {
    // Check if there is already a referral with same first name, last name and dob. If so return an error
    await Referral.find(
      {
        $and: [
          {
            last_name: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.last_name}$`, "i"),
            },
            first_name: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.first_name}$`, "i"),
            },
            dob: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.dob}$`, "i"),
            },
            project: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.project}$`, "i"),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      (err, response) => {
        if (response.length !== 0) {
          var message = {
            message:
              "Referral with the same First Name, Last Name and Date of Birth already exists.",
            type: "duplicate",
          }
          duplicate = true
          return res.status(400).json(message)
        }
      },
    )
  } else {
    new_referral
      .save()
      .then((referral) => {
        // If an agency adds a referral with 'Agency' field blank / None, send CBHS email that new referral was added
        if (
          referral.referral_agency === "None" ||
          referral.referral_agency === "CBHS" ||
          referral.referral_agency === ""
        ) {
          const send_to = "CBHS"
          updateAgencyNotification(send_to, referral.project[0])
        }
        return res.status(200).json(referral)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Validation error, missing keys on required fields for referral creation
        logger.error(req.originalUrl + err)
        if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
          missing_keys = []
          for (err in err.errors) {
            switch (err) {
              case "referral_source":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Source")
                break
              case "referral_source_email":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Source Email")
                break
              case "referral_need":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Need")
                break
              case "last_name":
                missing_keys.push("Last Name")
                break
              case "first_name":
                missing_keys.push("First Name")
                break
              case "middle_name":
                missing_keys.push("Middle Name")
                break
              case "gender":
                missing_keys.push("Gender")
                break
              case "address_1":
                missing_keys.push("Address 1")
                break
              case "county":
                missing_keys.push("County")
                break
              case "zip":
                missing_keys.push("Zipcode")
                break
              case "phone":
                missing_keys.push("Phone Number")
                break
            }
          }
          const validationError = {
            message: "Validation Error",
            fields: missing_keys,
          }
          return res.status(400).json(validationError)
        }
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your `nanoid` function, and the request handler which your frontend calls?

Comment: Hi, I added the function code to the original post for better formatting. I don't have any code for the nano_id in the request handler (Express). My thought there is it isn't coming in from the front end like a lot of the other values. I instantiate a new instance of the MySchema model, passing through the values that come in from the front end as some_property: req.body.some_property

Comment: Your schema and nanoid are fine, no async methods / promises here. Either the network request is failing (check the network tab in your browser console, or the request handler on your backend has an error and doesn't return. The nanoid doesn't need to come from the frontend, it is generated in the model's schema when a new instance of the model is made. Please share all of the code in the request handler which creates a new model.

Comment: Thanks, I added the request handler to the OP. Also tested in a sandbox app that uses the same tech stack (MERN) and it works there without a hitch. My hunch is the bug is in the front end where React validates the form and sets the state as loading. Still not 100% sure why forcing a hot reload by saving in VSCode fixes it, but it furthers my suspicion the bug is not on the back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem here was there was no logic to save when duplicate skip was false.

```
if (!payload.duplicate_skip)
```

so it looked for something with the same first, last and dob,

```
  await Referral.find(
      {
        $and: [
          {
            last_name: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.last_name}$`, "i"),
            },
            first_name: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.first_name}$`, "i"),
            },
            dob: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.dob}$`, "i"),
            },
            project: {
              $regex: new RegExp(`^${payload.project}$`, "i"),
            },
          },
        ],
      }
```

and if there was no match, it just did nothing.

the logic to save

```
else {
    new_referral
      .save()
      .then((referral) => {
        // If an agency adds a referral with 'Agency' field blank / None, send CBHS email that new referral was added
        if (
          referral.referral_agency === "None" ||
          referral.referral_agency === "CBHS" ||
          referral.referral_agency === ""
        ) {
          const send_to = "CBHS"
          updateAgencyNotification(send_to, referral.project[0])
        }
        return res.status(200).json(referral)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Validation error, missing keys on required fields for referral creation
        logger.error(req.originalUrl + err)
        if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
          missing_keys = []
          for (err in err.errors) {
            switch (err) {
              case "referral_source":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Source")
                break
              case "referral_source_email":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Source Email")
                break
              case "referral_need":
                missing_keys.push("Referral Need")
                break
              case "last_name":
                missing_keys.push("Last Name")
                break
              case "first_name":
                missing_keys.push("First Name")
                break
              case "middle_name":
                missing_keys.push("Middle Name")
                break
              case "gender":
                missing_keys.push("Gender")
                break
              case "address_1":
                missing_keys.push("Address 1")
                break
              case "county":
                missing_keys.push("County")
                break
              case "zip":
                missing_keys.push("Zipcode")
                break
              case "phone":
                missing_keys.push("Phone Number")
                break
            }
          }
          const validationError = {
            message: "Validation Error",
            fields: missing_keys,
          }
          return res.status(400).json(validationError)
        }
      })
  }
```

was never triggered when skip was false

so i added it after

```
 if (response.length !== 0) {
          var message = {
            message:
              "Referral with the same First Name, Last Name and Date of Birth already exists.",
            type: "duplicate",
          }
          duplicate = true
          return res.status(400).json(message)
        }
```

meaning, "after checking for a duplicate (skip is false), if you don't get anything back (response === 0), then go ahead and actually create and save a new instance of the model"